# twig templates not extends

Tags: twig, extends, slim

In Slim I use the twig templates.
I have in /views/email/auth/registered.php

```
{% extends 'email/templates/default.php' %}

{% block content %}
    You have registered!
{% endblock %}
```

and /views/email/templates/default.php I have

```
{% if auth %}
    <p>Hello {{ auth.getFullNameOrUsername }},</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Hello there,</p>
{% endif %}

{% block content %}{%  endblock %}
```

but when I render registered.php templates i Obtain only

```
You have registered!
```

the templates isnt extend `default.php`

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Did you take a look at the DOM in order to discard the option that the `<p>` is hidden? (and why are you naming your twig templates with a .php extension?)

Comment: Can you try to put them in the same directory and to reference each other using just the filename? Just a try but it could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the templates I use for generate email body, but in mail function I also set body of email, when I comment the body in mail function, now is template rendering ok.